# install Caffe on Ubuntu 16.04 error: fatal error: error writing to /tmp/cco9IwNP.s: No space left on device

Tags: ubuntu, server, caffe

I am installing the caffe on Ubuntu server  which followed the instruction: https://chunml.github.io/ChunML.github.io/project/Installing-Caffe-Ubuntu/, but there is error after I run the command: make all, as shown the image1, and there is memory information as shown image2

[image: errors] 
[image: memory info]

[image]

Comment: Can you run "df -h" and show us the output? I'm guessing you are running out of disk space. (tmp/ partition could be too small)

Comment: hi @Skynet thanks for your comment, please check the third image

Comment: As you can see /dev/sda is mounted to /. Thats where /tmp/ is located. Now you can either expand /dev/sda1 if it's possible or you create a new partition on /dev/sdb1 (which still has 1.5tb of free space) and mount it on /tmp/.

Comment: hi @Skynet thanks could you tell me in detail since I am not so good at linux. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running out of space on your / partition.

You have a few options now:

1. Make space on /dev/sda1
2. Expand /dev/sda1
3. Create a new partition for /tmp/ on another drive or in your RAM

I would choose 3. since it is just good practice to have a seperate partition mounted to /tmp/. (https://superuser.com/questions/442383/why-should-i-make-a-separate-partition-for-tmp)

The information for creating a new partiton and mounting it to /tmp is already on stackexchange so a little bit of searching should get you all the commands and explanations you need.

Example for mounting /tmp to RAM (Great for building stuff since its really fast):
https://askubuntu.com/questions/173094/how-can-i-use-ram-storage-for-the-tmp-directory-and-how-to-set-a-maximum-amount

Maybe someone who is familiar with creating and mounting partitions will make an edit to this answer containing the commands.

Comment: thanks for your comments. if there is command explanation will be the best since I am not familiar with linxu